# Pass Data $http.post From AngularJS and ASP.net MVC gets null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

i'm trying to pass data from AngularJS to ASP.net MVC and is always getting null.
Here's my code (only posting the essential, button, controller and c#:

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-grey btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="AddCar()">Save</a>
```

Controller

```
$scope.AddCar = function () {
            $http.post("Cars/AddCar", JSON.stringify($scope.new.JsonCar)).success(function (data) {
                Alert(ok)
            })
```

c#

```
public string AddCar(string JsonCar) 
        {
            try
           ....
        }
```

In JSON.stringify($scope.new.JsonCar) i'm getting this:

> "{"Name":"FIAT 500","Description":"New
>   car","MaxUserCapacity":5,"PhotoPath":"none"}"

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass your object directly as an object rather than stringifying it.  As it's being passed right now, it's a string, not an object that can properly be deserialized.

```
$http.post("Cars/AddCar", $scope.new.JsonCar).success(function (data) {
            Alert(ok)
        })
```

Create a Car object that matches your payload.  The serializer will handle your JSON object for you.

```
public Car AddCar(Car car) 
    {
        try
       ....
    }
```

My assumption is that at some point you are deserializing your string into an object regardless.  This just saves you that extra step.

Comment: it works, because now it sets the `contentType:"application/json"`

Answer (score 4):

Remove the JSON.stringify, your object is already JSON.

Add a [FromBody] attribute:

```
 public string AddCar([FromBody]string JsonCar) 
    {
        try
       ....
    }
```

Comment: The [FromBody] attribute tells MVC to get the value of the object from the body of the HTTP request.