# How to best pass and consume JSON data from angularJs to asp.net MVC - currently always has values set to null

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

This is similar to: [another stack overflow q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465390/pass-data-http-post-from-angularjs-and-asp-net-mvc-gets-null)

I have tried something similar to this question:

```
var MyItem= { "msg": "hello word!" };

$http.post("/MyController/testPost", MyItem).success(function (data) {
    Alert(ok)
})
```

I have also tried creating MyItem as a Javascript object.

Then in MyController:

```
[post]
public void testPost(MyItem MyItem)
{

 }
```

Where MyItem, looks like this:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string msg; 
}
```

The action in the controller is always hit in all scenarios, but MyItem is always has a null value for msg. Am I missing something? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Shouldn't the signature for `testPost` be `testPost(MyItem RiskItem)` and shouldn't your post be passing RiskItem instead of MyItem? Like `$http.post("/MyController/testPost", RiskItem)` ?

Comment: Thanks - that was a typo in writing my question - the problem still stands though

Comment: you said the Action gets hit, but does that particular method get hit? If you set a breakpoint inside `testPost` does it get hit?

Comment: Yes, it does. Just the msg value in the MyItem parameter is null. Actually, putting a breakpoint in the javacript post action, I can see that the value of msg is null before it is sent

Comment: That last comment is actually quite vital to getting a good answer to this question. Please consider editing it into the question, as it is a JavaScript problem, not an ASP.NET problem.

Comment: Good point. I didn't realise this bit of information until after I had asked it. I have updated the question now.

Comment: Actually, I was using visual studio to debug and I think this was giving me a deceptive debug message saying it is null. I debugged the js in the browser and the value is clearly set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it started to work when I had changed the "msg" field to property. No additional attributes except `[HttpPost]` for the controller.

```
    public class MyItem
    {
        public string msg { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult testPost(MyItem MyItem)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I just came in this morning and tried that (before looking at your post). Yes, that works, it needs to be a property, not a field. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try two options...

Try changing `var MyItem= { "msg": "hello word!" };` to..

```
var MyItem = { msg: "hello word!" };
```

**or**

```
var MyItem = {};
MyItem.msg = "hello world!";
```

Comment: Also strip out all the wcf attributed sh!t  and put [HttpPost] on your action

Comment: I have tried these and have just tried them again, but they also have a null msg even on the post method on the way in.

Comment: haha, those attributes are also gone Matt - I just tried those in because nothing seems to work

Comment: @Sam have you looked at this -- http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not work unfortunately - the config updates correctly, but the same issues remain.

Comment: I'm shooting in the dark here since I'm not too familiar with AngularJs, but from what I've read, would setting the variable like `$scope.MyItem = { msg: "hello world!" };` and then passing it like `$http.post("/MyController/testPost", $scope.MyItem)` work?